# Get access to ES6 class in gulpfile.js

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, gulp, es6-class, es6-modules

I want to get access to ES6 class from another file in my `gulpfile.js`. It looks like that unable to use `import`:

```
import MyClass from './development/myFramework/MyClass';

const instanceOfMyClass = new MyClass();
```

> C:\MyIDE\projects\myProject\gulpfile.js:3 import MyClass from
>   './development/myFramework/MyClass'; ^^^^^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected
>   token import

Up to this point I always got the access to ES6-class from another folder by `import` and don't know, how to do it by `require` properly.

First: I know that some web-browsers don't understand ES6 modules, but what about Node.JS runtime?

And then, how I need to get access to `MyClass` and the properly create the instance? Is `require` the only way?

Comment: Use `require('./development/myFramework/MyClass');` for now.

Comment: @MikaS, thank you for the comment answer. Is the following code correct?  
 `const MyClass = require('./development/myFramework/MyClass');
let myClassInstance = MyClass();` I suppose the shorthand `let myClassInstance = require('./development/myFramework/MyClass');` is invalid, is not it?

Comment: It depends on how the file with MyClass is set up. You also have to change from `export` to `module.exports` inside it. You can read more about it [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-module-exports-vs-exports-ec7e254d63ac). It should be quite similar to what you are used to with import/export. And I don't think you can use classes in the current version of Node without using Babel.